# PyQt5 QTabWidget showing currentWidget() "NoneType"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qwebengineview

I'm building a simple browser with python, PyQt5 QWebEnjineView.

I want to make the reload button to be hidden when the page is loading and "stop loading" button visible,
When loading is finished, then reload button will be visible again and "stop loading" button will be hidden.

My QWebEnjineView is in a method called add_new_tab and I've defined QTabWidget as self.tabs in the ****init**** method.

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__()
        
        # create tabs
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        
        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)

        self.tabs.currentWidget().loadProgress.connect(self.loadProgressHandler)
        self.tabs.currentWidget().loadFinished.connect(self.loadFinishedHandler)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

        # self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()


        # nav bar
        self.navbar = QToolBar()
        self.navbar.setMovable(False)
        self.addToolBar(self.navbar)

        # Refresh button
        self.reload_butn = QPushButton(self, text="Reload")
        self.reload_butn.clicked.connect(self.reload_tab)

        # Set reload button visible
        self.reload_butn.setHidden(False)

        # Stop button
        self.stop_btn = QPushButton(self, text="Stop")
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_loading_tab)
        self.stop_btn.setHidden(True)

        # Set stop_butn hidden initially
        self.stop_btn.setHidden(True)
        
        # Add Refresh and Stop button
        self.navbar.addWidget(self.stop_btn)
        self.navbar.addWidget(self.reload_butn)
        
       # Add Address bar
        self.url_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.url_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        self.navbar.addWidget(self.url_bar)

        # on startup
        self.add_new_tab(QUrl("https://www.google.com/"), "Homepage")
        self.show()
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def loadProgressHandler(self, prog):
        self.stop_btn.setHidden(False)  # When any page is loading, then stop_butn will visible
        self.reload_butn.setHidden(True)    # When any page is loading, then reload_butn will hidde  

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def loadFinishedHandler(self):
        self.reload_butn.setHidden(False)    # When loading is finished, then reload_butn will be visible again for the user
        self.stop_btn.setHidden(True)   # When load finished, stop button will be hidden

    # reload tab
    def reload_tab(self):
        self.tabs.currentWidget().reload()
    
    def stop_loading_tab(self):
        self.tabs.currentWidget().stop()    

    def close_current_tab(self, i):
        if self.tabs.count() < 2 :
            return
        self.tabs.removeTab(i)
    
    # stop load current tab
    def stop_loading_tab(self):
        self.tabs.currentWidget().stop()    

    # doubleclick on empty space for new tab
    def tab_open_doubleclick(self, i):
        if i == -1: # No tab under the click
            self.add_new_tab(QUrl("http://www.google.com/"), label="New tab")
    
  

    # function to add new tab
    def add_new_tab(self, qurl=None, label="Blank"):
        if qurl is None:
            qurl = QUrl('https://www.google.com/')
        
        browser = QWebEngineView()
        browser.setUrl(qurl)
        i = self.tabs.addTab(browser, label)

        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i)


    def navigate_to_url(self): 
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(QUrl(self.url_bar.text()))



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setApplicationName("browser")
window = mainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

I have some button for reload, back, home etc. where I called `self.tabs.currentWidget().reload()` for example in the reload method,
But when I'm adding `self.tabs.currentWidget().loadProgress.connect(self.loadProgressHandler)`
for the operation, then It's giving me a error

```
    self.tabs.currentWidget().loadProgress.connect(self.loadProgressHandler)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loadProgress'
```

Can anyone tell me why is it showing that the self.tabs.currentWidget() is NoneType?
Is there a way to fix it? Ask me if you need more details

Thank you!

Comment: *Where* do you try to connect? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is:

```py
self.tabs.currentWidget().loadProgress.connect(self.loadProgressHandler)
self.tabs.currentWidget().loadFinished.connect(self.loadFinishedHandler)
```

Where the OP is assuming that the connection will occur with all the pages, and that is incorrect since it will only occur with the current widget which in that case is None causing the error.

In this case the solution is to connect each QWebEngineView created and check in the slots if the sender() matches the currentWidget().

1. remove

   ```py
   self.tabs.currentWidget().loadProgress.connect(self.loadProgressHandler)
   self.tabs.currentWidget().loadFinished.connect(self.loadFinishedHandler)
   ```
2. add connection:

   ```py
   def add_new_tab(self, qurl=None, label="Blank"):
       if qurl is None:
           qurl = QUrl('https://www.google.com/')
       browser = QWebEngineView()

       browser.loadProgress.connect(self.loadProgressHandler)
       browser.loadFinished.connect(self.loadFinishedHandler)

       i = self.tabs.addTab(browser, label)
       self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i)

       browser.load(qurl)
   ```
3. Validate:

   ```py
   @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
   def loadProgressHandler(self, prog):
       if self.tabs.currentWidget() is not self.sender():
           return
       self.stop_btn.show()
       self.reload_butn.hide()

   @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
   def loadFinishedHandler(self):
       if self.tabs.currentWidget() is not self.sender():
           return
       self.reload_butn.show()
       self.stop_btn.hide()
   ```

---

### Update:

There are the following errors:

- The visibility of the widgets added to the QToolBar are managed using the associated QActions.
- Instead of managing 2 slots associated with the progress and completion of loading, only one of them should be used since, for example, the associated slot is also called when it is loaded at 100% so it could be hidden since it can be invoked together with finished.
- It is better to verify that the variables that can be None to avoid exceptions.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLineEdit,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QTabWidget,
    QToolBar,
)
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class mainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tabs = QTabWidget(tabsClosable=True)

        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)

        self.navbar = QToolBar(movable=True)
        self.addToolBar(self.navbar)

        self.reload_butn = QPushButton(self, text="Reload")
        self.reload_butn.clicked.connect(self.reload_tab)

        self.stop_btn = QPushButton(self, text="Stop")
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_loading_tab)

        self.url_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.url_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)

        self.stop_action = self.navbar.addWidget(self.stop_btn)
        self.reload_action = self.navbar.addWidget(self.reload_butn)
        self.navbar.addWidget(self.url_bar)

        self.stop_action.setVisible(False)

        self.add_new_tab(QUrl("https://www.google.com/"), "Homepage")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.showMaximized()

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def loadProgressHandler(self, prog):
        if self.tabs.currentWidget() is not self.sender():
            return
        loading = prog < 100
        self.stop_action.setVisible(loading)
        self.reload_action.setVisible(not loading)

    def reload_tab(self):
        self.tabs.currentWidget().reload()

    def stop_loading_tab(self):
        self.tabs.currentWidget().stop()

    def close_current_tab(self, i):
        if self.tabs.count() < 2:
            return
        self.tabs.removeTab(i)

    def stop_loading_tab(self):
        if self.tabs.currentWidget() is None:
            return
        self.tabs.currentWidget().stop()

    def tab_open_doubleclick(self, i):
        if i == -1:
            self.add_new_tab(QUrl("http://www.google.com/"), label="New tab")

    def add_new_tab(self, qurl=None, label="Blank"):
        if qurl is None:
            qurl = QUrl("https://www.google.com/")
        browser = QWebEngineView()
        browser.loadProgress.connect(self.loadProgressHandler)
        i = self.tabs.addTab(browser, label)
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i)
        browser.load(qurl)

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        if self.tabs.currentWidget() is None:
            return
        self.tabs.currentWidget().load(QUrl.fromString(self.url_bar.text()))


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("browser")
    window = mainWindow()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, but my QWebEnjineView is not in the constructor, it's in the add_new_tab method, is there a way to do this from the add_new_tab? If not, then I have to do lot of refactoring.

Comment: @SaminSakur Have you made the detailed changes that I indicate? Please apply the changes that I indicate and tell me that it does not work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wanted the to make the reload button to be hidden when the page is loading and "stop loading" button visible, When loading is finished, then reload button will be visible again and "stop loading" button will be hidden but this doesn't work, do you have any idea why?

Comment: thaks a lot for your help and it works fine now.